# $\overline{A}=A\cup \delta A$ proof

Tags: general-topology

Can somebody help me out with proving the following equality?

$\overline{A}=A\cup \delta A$ where $\delta A=\overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about the definition.

Comment: @ClementC.: $\overline A$ denotes the adherence of $A$, hence you don't have $\overline A\cap \overline{A^c} = \overline{A\cup A^c}$.

Comment: $A\cup\delta A=A\cup(\bar A\cap\bar {A^c})=(A\cup\bar A)\cap(A\cup\bar {A^c})$

since $A\subset\bar A\Rightarrow(A\cup\bar A)=\bar A$

and $(A\cup\bar {A^c})\supset(A\cup A^c)=\mathbb R$ then,

$(A\cup\bar A)\cap(A\cup\bar {A^c})\supset\bar A\cap\mathbb R=\bar A$

Comment: Thanks! But is it right that this is a proof only in one way? It proofs that $\overline{A}$ is a subset of $\overline{A} \cup \delta A$?

Comment: @RoosJansen I'm not sure if it's correct, maybe the assumption that $A\subset\bar A$ is not allowed.

Comment: @FPE: my apologies -- I use both $A^c$ and $\overline{A}$ (although  usually not at the same place) to denote the complement of $A$; I got mixed up.

Comment: Anyone who can help?

Comment: @RoosJansen: can you state your definition of $\overline A$? I'll write an answer that match your definitions.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I forgot to say.  If A is a subset of X then $\overline{A}$ contains all points x in X such that the points x are closure points of A.